# Different vector notations

Tags: notation, vectors

I've encountered at least the following vector notations:
$ \overline{a}, \ \underline{a}, \ \vec{a},  $ and **a**.

Are they alternative notations for the same thing, or is $\vec{a}$ only for physical vectors (dimension $ \le 3)$, for example? Or is it about where the vector begins?

I guess **a** is always ok, but how about $\overline{a} \ \mathrm{and} \ \underline{a}$?

Comment: If it's any help, I've mostly seen $\bar{v}$ in more algebraic classes and $\vec{v}$ in physics or analysis. I have no idea if those are the normal conventions or why those conventions exist, but I just figured I'd throw that out there.

Comment: Vectors are vectors, however they happen to be notated.  Different groups of people may prefer certain notations over others, and for historical or preferential reasons one notation might be dominant over another in those contexts... but in the end it doesn't matter so long as it is clear what is meant.  Other than for historical reasons, often one might choose to notate in a particular way so that objects of different types are visually distinct... like how matrices are often capital letters while vectors are lowercase, or functions start from $f$ while variables start from $x$ and so on...

Comment: I was introduced to this one: $\vec a$.

Comment: I've certainly seen each of these, as well as using a hat to emphasize when one is a unit vector like $\hat{\imath},\hat{\jmath},\hat{k}$, but I personally don't bother with any specific notation and just use vectors $u,v,x,b$ without any bars, arrows, or boldface.  I find $Ax=b$ in the context makes it clear enough already which is vector and which is matrix without need to further distinguish.

Comment: In higher level maths books if often goes back to plain old $a$ too

Comment: They all mean the same thing. My new personal favorite way of distinguishing different mathematical objects when typesetting is to use different fonts. Scalars [ order $0$ tensors ] I write in in default font:
$$A,a,B,b,C,c,\dots$$
Vectors [order $1$ tensors ]I write in roman upright font:
$$\mathrm{A,a,B,b,C,c}$$
General higher order [$2+$] tensors I write in bold:
$$\mathbf{A,a,B,b,C,c}$$
For roman font use `\mathrm` and for bolded font use `\mathbf`. If you want to write a Greek letter in bold you can use `\boldsymbol`.